# Mocking and interface implementation

Tags: c#, mocking

I have c# net project and using nunit for testing .

I have a class called xyz that has implementation of session class. The session class is an inbuilt class which is part of a dll that I am referencing in my project.

I need to mock the session class in my test project . When I try to mock the session class , I get an error message saying you can only mock overridable methods or interfaces.

So I thought of implementing a class that extends the session class and then create an interface for that class. I would then mock the interface and call base class methods . Does this sound a good solution or does anyone have better ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an interface say ISessionService. Add all the methods that you need to mock in this interface. Create a class SessionManager that implements this interface. In the implemention of this methods call the actual methods. Now you can mock the methods using the interface.

```
public class xyz : ISessionService
    {
        public string AddCustomer(AddCustomerRequest addCustomerRequest)
        {   
            using (SessionService service = new SessionService())
            { 
                response = service.AddCustomer(addCustomerRequest);
            }
            return response;
        }
}
```

Comment: Do i need to inherit the base class first ?

Comment: You need not inherit. In implementation of your class you can call the  methods of actual session service. I have update the code. Hope it helps